# Making android GridView not distort images

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am using GridView to display a perfect square number of pictures ( say 9, i.e. 3X3). The pictures are all the same size originally. But When they appear on the GridView, they are distorted. Is there a way to get GridView to display images in their actual size without distortion?

Also the images are sent to the View Dynamically using an image adapter [as shown in the official android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

Edit:

I am thinking of extending GridView with my own CustomView, but then I don't know what to override and how:

```
public class CustomView extends GridView{ ... }
```